# group_add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetimelike' in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to execute below code and getting error

```
Grouping=Group_Payer.groupby('Group')['Total'].sum()
```

> error:group_add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetimelike'

Comment: can you post the full error message with stack trace?

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\groupby.pyx", line 482, in pandas._libs.groupby.group_add

TypeError: group_add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetimelike'

Comment: and what version of pandas are you running? (x.x.x)

Comment: pandas version 1.3.5

Comment: I am trying to sum column with integer value, any integer value might pass as datetime in sum(). But i checked datatype it shows int

Comment: I can see that datetimelike seems to be a valid parameter to group_add() https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/_libs/groupby.pyx#L487

This makes me think there might be something wrong with your environment.  Are you running your code within a virtual environment?